# nginx proxy_pass not passing request to docker app on port 8000

Tags: django, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```bash
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/../staticfiles;
    }

    location /api/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I checked whether my app is running on port 8000 through `docker ps` command. Here is the log:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                       NAMES
f86d5f013c90   lead-hr-api-backend   "bash -c ./run.sh"       18 hours ago   Up 18 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   lbhr-backend
```

Nginx error logs: `sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log`

```bash
2024/01/30 11:51:53 [error] 59675#59675: *283 recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.69.165.44, server: leadhr.alexpy.com, request: "GET /api/admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/api/admin/login/?next=/api/admin/"
2024/01/30 11:52:16 [error] 59675#59675: *283 recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.69.165.44, server: leadhr.alexpy.com, request: "GET /api/admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/", host: "leadhr.alexpy.com"
```

Later I dug a bit deeper and found the Unknown error was `connection reset by peer`. I don't remember how I found the error, but it was that.

Interestingly, when I run my api server using gunicorn, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is the NGINX server running in a docker container, on your host machine ?

Comment: @ABWassim no, I am using the nginx without docker.

Comment: Any logs form the container? `docker logs lbhr-backend` also did you tried call `curl -vv http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/` what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem in the past. I resolved it by using the following nginx.conf. Check if this works.

```
upstream microservice_app { # name of our web image
    server localhost:8000; # default django port
}

server {

    listen 80; # default external port. Anything coming from port 80 will go through NGINX

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://microservice_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```